# New list input not updating function results

Tags: python, list, function

I am pretty new to python and I recently started this project. I feel like I am very close but I cannot tell why my values will not update when I input a new set of numbers? I think it is a problem in the last function. Picture describing:

[image]

```
def cow_bull():
    game=True
    idx=0
    cow=0       # Guessed a numb correctly in wrong place
    bull=0      #Guessed numb correctly in correct place
    count=1
    while True:
        n=(player_list("Enter your guess!: "))
        while idx < len(n):
            if n == game_list_official:
                print("You WIN!!!, It took you", count, "attempt!!!")
                break
            elif n[idx] == game_list_official[idx]:
                bull+=1                                                                               
            elif n[idx] in game_list_official and n[idx] != game_list_official[idx]:                      
                cow+=1
            idx+=1
            count+=1

        print("cow",cow,"bull",bull)

cow_bull()
```

Comment: Hey, can you please provide us the full code?

Comment: Hi, perhaps the `idx` variable and the others need to be reset to `0` in your `while` loop?

Comment: Instead of a while loop, use `for idx in range(len(n)):`

Comment: Are the data types the same? `game_list_official` looks like a list of integers, is that what `player_list()` returns?

Comment: It won't let me upload the full list of code because it is too long. I will try some recommendations posted here. //changing the while loop to a for loop did the trick! Can you explain why that is?//